# randomly change a 2D array based on percentage in Powershell

Tags: powershell, percentage

I'm trying to randomly change an array based on a variable percentage in Powershell.
unfortunaly I dont get the expected output.
In the script below I'm trying to change 20% of the array based on a random generated output.

Does somebody know the best way to acomplisch this?

```
    $row = 4
    $col = 2

    $temp_array = New-Object 'object[,]' $row,$col
    for ($i=0;$i -le $row -1 ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j -le $col -1 ; $j++) {
            $temp_array[$i,$j] = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10 
        }
    }


    $perc_to_change = 0.2


    for ($i=0;$i -le $row -1 ; $i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j -le $col -1 ; $j++) {
            $check_digit = Get-Random -Maximum 1 -Minimum 0.0
            If($check_digit -lt $perc_to_change){
                $temp_array[$i,$j] = "changed"
            }
            Write-Host "temp array [" $i "][" $j "] = " $temp_array[$i,$j]
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are testing for `greater than 20%`. [*grin*] change the test to `-le` and it will work.

Comment: I noticed afther I posted :) 
unfortanly (because its randomly set) it doen't change exact 20% but in the neighberhoud of 20%...
Is there a way to change it spot-on 20%?

Comment: i would use `$Pct = 20` and a random range of 20, 40, 60, etc. to get 5 steps of random values. last, test for that random selection with `-eq $Pct`. that will give you one-out-of-five.

Comment: @hexedecimal, you want to change all items in array by 20% or you want to get change for 20% of items from array?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey could you show an test-code of what you mean?
I'm not realy sure in what you mean :) (I'm rather new at Powershell)

Comment: @KirillPashkov - I want to change 20% of the given array, so for instance:  20 array-elements out of an 2D array whit 100 elements.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you need a different apprach to get the random percentage spread over rows and columns.

Uniquely number rows and columns

```
      C0 C1 C2 C3 C4
R0    0  1  2  3  4
R1    5  6  7  8  9
R2    10 11 12 13 14
R3    15 16 17 18 19
R4    20 21 22 23 24
```

This script uses `Get-Random -Count` to select the percentage from the multiplication of $rows by $cols, iterates the results and recalculates row and column.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\23\SO_52949282.ps1
$row = 5
$col = 5

$temp_array = New-Object 'object[,]' $row,$col
for ($i=0;$i -le $row -1 ; $i++) {
    for ($j=0;$j -le $col -1 ; $j++) {
        $temp_array[$i,$j] = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
    }
}

$elements = $row * $col
$Count    = [Math]::Floor($elements * 0.2)

0..$($elements-1) | Get-Random -Count $count | ForEach-Object {
    "{0,2} = [{1},{2}]" -f $_,[Math]::Floor($_/$col),($_ % $col )
}
```

What you do with the resulting percentage I'll leave up to you.

Sample output (20% of 5*5 is 5):

```
 6 = [1,1]
11 = [2,1]
16 = [3,1]
 9 = [1,4]
19 = [3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

for what i meant by a better match to your `exactly 20%` request, take a look at this ...

```
$TargetPct = 20
$ValueRange = @(20, 40, 60, 80, 100)

$Results = 1..100 |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Random -InputObject $ValueRange
        }

($Results -eq $TargetPct).Count
```

the above will show counts that are consistently near the ideal 20% of 100. i ran the code several times and the count of "exactly 20" ranged from 17 to 23.

using the `-InputObject` parameter gets around the "off by one" that the `-Max` parameter gives you.

- `-Min 10 -Max 20` >>> 10..19
- `-InputObject (10..20)` >>> 10..20